# Isolated power supplies for high-voltage DC

Tags: arduino, dc, high-voltage, digital-potentiometer, arcing

I am currently designing a high-voltage system for electrospinning. I am looking for some advice to address arcing and how to isolate the high-voltage DC from the low-voltage DC.

In my current setup I have two power supplies:

1. The first one is a 3-pin, 240 VAC to 24 VDC power supply that powers the logic circuitry for controlling the high voltage through a digital potentiometer ([MCP45HV51](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/OTH/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/20005304A.pdf)) and a high-temperature heater that is wrapped around the (+) terminal of the high voltage.
2. The second one is a 2-pin, 240 VAC to 24 VDC power supply that powers the 24 VDC to 20 kVDC [high-voltage supply](http://www.gammahighvoltage.com/html/series_rc.html) as well as a digital voltmeter to display the current voltage. The high voltage is controlled through an analog signal between 0 and 10 VDC that is referenced to the high-voltage ground.

When the high voltage is switched on there are arcing sounds that emanate from the control circuitry which is concerning.

Is the method of two power supplies enough to isolate the high voltage from the low voltage?

Could the digital potentiometer be causing the arcing sounds?

This is my current wiring setup:

[image: Block Diagram of control setup]

Comment: **THIS MACHINE KILLS**. Are you really running the heater at 24 kV? If you don't know with as much certainty as possible that isolation is life-safe then don't even think about using ituntil it is fully guaranteed to be "almost perfect" <- RM copied from below .......................................................................................

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: run it in the dark anmd look for actual arcing. yuo might just be hearing inductors singing.

Comment: can you put the heat coil on the other side of the gap. the side that's closer to ground potential. insulating the heat coils against 24KV would seem tricky.

Comment: using a battery to power the heat coil could be another solution.

Comment: Isolation at 20 kV is *really difficult*.

Comment: **THIS MACHINE KILLS**. Are you really running the heater at 24 kV? If you don't know with as much certainty as possible that isolation is life-safe then don't even think about using ituntil it is fully guaranteed to be "almost perfect"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem with HV transients coupled through relay capacitance. Finally a protection between the rely coil and the relay driver helped.

Your high voltage node may arc and this produces very aggressive transients, which can couple through the heater and the relay back to the Arduino.

L1, C1 and C2 are the primary firewall, R4 and C5 are a 2nd stage to protect the BJT.

The grounding concept is important here. All transients, that go through the relay, are sent to GND with a low inductance path.

I recommend a 10 kHz PWM drive using an isolated gate driver with 35 kV/us strength to set the target voltage here. An unisolated digital potentiometer is not safe.

You can feed the heater and the HV generator with one supply, they are on the "dirty side" of the circuit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvMN3x.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Awesome, thank you for this information, I tried driving the high voltage supply with a manual potentiometer which still caused issues and arcing to be heard in the 24V power supply of the heater and between the HV and heater, we are using an SSR to control the heater, would this effect anything or it is preferred to use a conventional relay. I was wondering what the component U2 was?

Comment: @Lambcd15 There was a typo in the schematic. I suggest to use an isolated gate driver like SI8261 (here U2). I would prefer a classic relay here or make my own SSR (FETs and isolator),, that can safely operate under HV transients.